# How to keep unrelated workbooks open in excel when running a macro

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel

I am writing a macro in VB in excel 2013. The only remaining bug left is when the macro runs, all of the other workbooks i have open close, even ones unrelated to the macro. I do not want users of my macro to lose other tabs of excel they may have open if they run my program. I have tried using "Application.Visible = true" but it is not giving me the desired behavior. Is there a way to run a macro without affecting any other currently open workbooks? Or is it possible that something else I have written is overriding the Application.Visible method? If someone could provide a recommendation it would be much appreciated.

Comment: VB.NET doesnt do macros, so please remove the tag, and please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: nah, thats not necessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Application.Visible = false
```

Simply does what it says, set the application "Excel in your case" to invisible.

If you want to hide something specific you have to call this:

e.g Sheet

```
Sheets("Whatever").Visible = False
```

e.g Workbook

```
ActiveWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = False
//ActiveWorkbook needs to have an reference to the specified Workbook which you get as an example if you store the opening of the workbook (ActiveWorkbook = Workbooks.Open )
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a line

```
 Workbooks.close
```

(which will close all workbooks) when what you wanted to do was close the specific workbook with the macro. That should be

```
 ThisWorkbook.Close
```